# Is this jns ever false? eflag in x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I am reading some assembly, and I'm fairly sure that I have some logically impossible/dead code in it. Here it is:

```
shr       %eax
test      %eax, %eax
jns       0x[something]
[if body]
[something]
```

Is it ever, in any case, possible for the if-body to get executed? I feel like the answer is no, but then again, wouldn't the compiler optimize this out?

Apologize for the vagueness in the code, didn't want to add more code than was necessary to give the question context. Let me know if more information would be useful.

Comment: Yeah, given the information provided, the sign bit will never be set. It's either missed optimization, or there is some important detail in code not shown (such as maybe a jump going to the `test` from elsewhere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is a branch directly to the if-body from somewhere else, it cannot possibly be reached through that `jns`.  The `shr` (logical shift right) instruction will always result in a high bit (sign bit) of zero, so that `test` and `jns` will always have the same behavior no matter what value `eax` started out with.

That said, it would be worthwhile to search elsewhere in the code and see if anything jumps to the `test`, or to the `jnz`, or to the `[if body]`, since those instructions might still not be dead code if they're reachable another way.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look out for jumps.